# Xpath: How to check if a tag comes before text or after text?

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

Assume I have the following two example pieces of HTML:

`<p>This is some text: <b>ABCD12345</b></p>`

`<p><b>Name:</b> John Doe</p>`

I'm able to separate the `<b>` and non-`<b>` parts, but I (also) want to know how to determine whether the `<b>` part is at the start or at the end of the text (in other words; whether it has text before or after). How to do that?

I'm using Python (with lxml) if it matters (I don't think it really does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
not(/p/b/following-sibling::text())
```

will return true iff there are no text nodes following `b` in `p`, as in your first case:

```
<p>This is some text: <b>ABCD12345</b></p>
```

---

This XPath,

```
not(/p/b/preceding-sibling::text())
```

will return true iff there are no text nodes preceding `b` in `p`, as in your second case:

```
<p><b>Name:</b> John Doe</p>
```

---

If it's not the absence but the presence of text before/after the `b` element that's of interest, you can change the `not()` to `boolean()` in those XPath expressions.

Comment: Cool! That works like a charm. I didn't know `text()` could be used in such a way too. Learned something new today. Thank you! :)